# Server Control generates unexpected markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, htmltextwriter

I am building a database editor/line-of-business tool for a client using .NET 4.0, and IIS 7.  I want to conditionally include some HTML in my page based on values I have stored in Session.  I am doing this on the server-side, and to encapsulate the code, I created an ASP Server Control.

As you will see, the markup generated by the Server Control is not what I expected.  I am hoping someone out there has seen this before and can help me understand how to control the markup generation output.

Here's the new RenderContents for a control called MyList.  It is supposed to generate new list entries using the <li> tag.

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
    output.WriteEncodedText(this.Text);
    output.RenderEndTag();
}
```

After compiling the main project, and adding a reference to MyList, I use MyList in the following HTML:

```
<h1>Favorite Things</h1>
<ul>
    <cc1:MyList ID="mL1" runat="server" Text="Code that works!" />
    <cc1:MyList ID="mL2" runat="server" Text="Going home before 8" />
    <cc1:MyList ID="mL3" runat="server" Text="Cold drinks in fridge" />
</ul>
```

And it generates the following:

```
<h1>Favorite Things</h1>
<ul>
    <span id="MainContent_mL1"><li>Code that works!</li></span>
    <span id="MainContent_mL2"><li>Going home before 8</li></span>
    <span id="MainContent_mL3"><li>Cold drinks in fridge</li></span>
</ul>
```

Now I add a test based on a Session value.  The Page property of WebControl provides me a reference to the control's container, and thus access to my Session:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    string backcolor = "Yellow";
    if (this.Page.Session["access"] == null) {
        backcolor = "Red";
    }
    output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
    output.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, backcolor);
    output.WriteEncodedText(this.Text);
    output.RenderEndTag();
}
```

Now the markup begins to unravel.  Note the inconsistency in 'mL1':

```
<h1>Favorite Things</h1>
<ul>
    <span id="MainContent_mL1"><li>Code that works!</li></span>
    <span id="MainContent_mL2" style="background-color:Red;"><li>Going home before 8</li></span>
    <span id="MainContent_mL3" style="background-color:Red;"><li>Cold drinks in fridge</li></span>
</ul>
```

In my real code, which is more complex, the markup turned into just the `span` tags.  And, when I set breakpoints in `RenderContents()` it only got called once when I had five tags in a row.

Other info:
The page with cc1:MyList controls has EnableSession=true.  My web.config specifies the normal Session manager ('rml', and 'RoleBasedList' refer to my 'real' control, which I simplified to isolate the problem and make this post shorter):

```
<system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="20" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="rml" assembly="RoleBasedList" namespace="SOTS.ServerControls"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </httpModules>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

And now you know everything I do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the `WebControl.TagKey` property in your custom server control:

```
protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
{
    get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Li; }
}
```

The default value is `Span`, which explains what you're seeing.  Of course, if you do this, you don't render the Li tag in your `RenderContents` override.

An alternative would be to override `Render`, to take full control of the rendering, or to derive from `Control` instead.  But you'll lose some of the features of `WebControl`, notably styles for your outer tag.

Regarding your second problem, you are calling:

```
output.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, backcolor);
```

which adds a style attribute to be applied to the next call to `RenderBeginTag`.  You don't call `RenderBeginTag`, so this is applied to a tag in the next control in the tree.

Another point is `Session` will be null when your control is rendered in the Visual Studio designer.  You should check for null, or alternatively check if you're running in design mode:

```
if ((Site != null) && (Site.DesignMode))
{
    ... running in design mode, Session won't be available
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `System.Web.UI.WebControls`. I suggest you subclass `System.Web.UI.Control` directly.

The `<span>` is being inserted by the class you're deriving from (which you haven't mentioned). Note that you're overriding `RenderContents` instead of `Render`, which means that the control superclass is free to wrap the output of `RenderContents` with whatever it wishes, in this case `<span>`.